# Samsung Galaxy J7 Core non responsive to back button and menu button

Tags: applications, buttons, menu

I am using Samsung Galaxy J5 Core. I accidentally clicked on an advertisement on a site, which caused the back and menu buttons to not respond.
I've tried using two Security Antivirus and scanning shows no viruses either. What is the cause of this problem?

Comment: Have you rebooted the phone?

Comment: Yes, i did reboot, data reset and wipe cache but all of them without any change

Comment: What you you mean by "data reset"? Is it factory reset? Please note that you are using an Android device which runs an Android version that is dangerously vulnerable to user's privacy and Operating system's integrity. If a factory reset did not solve your problem then you *might* have been infected with a system level malware, although, detailed investigation is warranted here to rule out resouce constraints (slow storage, bugs, and what not).

Comment: @Firelord Yes, i meant factory reset. so, how i can fix the infection of system level malware? It's very annoying -_-